# non-https AWS API Gateway for custom domains?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, https, aws-api-gateway

I have a fairly simple pipeline AWS API Gateway -> AWS Lambda that parses incoming request path and redirect to a different domain with HTTP 301.

The pipeline is deployed publicly so you could test it yourself.

Doesn't work

- http://docs.avoncondo.com/test

Works fine (https)

- https://docs.avoncondo.com/test

Expected outcome: redirects to a Google Docs page that contains one sentence "Redirect works as expected!  "
(that's the reason I built this pipeline as `google` domain is banned in one of 3rd party applications where I need to send urls to)

I added "avoncondo.com" as a custom domain under API Gateway.
It seems forces to have an SSL certificate, which I purchased on AWS ACM.

There is no way to do non-https, old-fashioned `http` on AWS API Gateway when using a custom domain? I hope I miss something basic.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/ "Amazon API Gateway does not support unencrypted (HTTP) endpoints." (under the "Can I create HTTPS endpoints?" question)